# Importing wsdl in Delphi don't add soap header

Tags: web-services, delphi, wsdl, delphi-2010

I have problem when I import wsdl in Delphi. My soap header is not added in my binding.
What is the problem ?

```
<wsdl:operation name="singleSms">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:header use="literal" part="request_header" message="tns:identityHeader"></soap:header>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

http://www.smsconnect.ma:8000/wsdl/MCMS.wsdl

Comment: Which Delphi version? Older Delphi versions don't offer complete support for SOAP.

Comment: as written in tag Delphi 2010